# Have a for loop switching between specified values

Tags: swift, loops, for-loop, swift3

I'm working with Swift 3 and Xcode.

I'd like to do something like this :

```
for i in -3,4,12,0
{ ... }
```

So i takes the value -3, then 4 then 12 and so on...

I know this is possible in some languages, I saw this syntax :

```
for v = [1 5 8 17]
disp(v)
end
```

But is it possible to do it in Swift ?

Comment: I tried a lot of syntaxes but not this one... And I didn't see this kind of syntax in the Swift documentation in the "Collection Types" section, thanks.

Comment: Just for reference - it's under *Creating an Array with an Array Literal*: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do either

```
for i in [-3, 4, 12, 0] {
    //Do whatever you want to do
}
```

or you do

```
let myArray = [-3, 4, 12, 0]

for i in myArray {
    //Do whatever you want to do
}
```

if you want to reuse the array.